# Rails merge function within the create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone explain this line for me?

```
@order = Order.new orders_param.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"], card_token: stripe_params["stripeToken"])
```

First time seeing `merge` being used in a controller action. What is it doing?

From what I know both `email` and `card_token` are later used in the Model. Is this simply done to pass the parameters call into the model, or are there any other uses for `merge`?

Comment: Did you try reading the [merge](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) documentation? If so, what specifically didn't you understand about this use of merge?

Comment: Probably pre-populating `email` and `card_token` fields in the form!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` is applied to the `orders_param` hash. It generates a new hash from `orders_param` hash added with `:email` and `card_token` keys with their corresponding values (`stripe_params["StripEmail"]` and `stripe_params["stripeToken"]`.

The produced hash is used for initializing a new `Order`.